# aggregate data and list frequencies of a variable in a string

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following datatable

```
dt<-data.table(string=c("A","A","A","B","B","C"), source=c("a","b","c","a","b","a"), N=rep(1,6))
    string source  N
1:      A      a   1
2:      A      b   1
3:      A      c   1
4:      B      a   1
5:      B      b   1
6:      C      a   1
```

What I would like to have, is an aggregated table of the following form:

```
   string   a_b_c
1:      A   1|1|1
2:      B   1|1|0
3:      C   1|0|0
```

That means, I would like to drop the column with the source of N, but keep this information in a new column that contains information whether we have information from source a|b|c. The problem is that I do not know how to add the missing 0 if we do not have this information in the original dt.

If I try the code
`dt <- dt[, paste(N, collapse="|"), by = string]`, I get something like this:

```
   string     V1
 1:      A  1|1|1
 2:      B    1|1
 3:      C      1
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `dcast(dt, string ~ source, sum)`? OR you can use `length` if you just want a binary result

Comment: "I would like to drop the column with the source of N, but keep this information in a new column that contains information whether we have information from source a|b|c" -- not a good idea, but ... following on from David's code ... `dcast(melt(dcast(dt, string ~ source, sum), id="string"), string ~ ., fun.agg=paste, collapse="|")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
dcast(dt,string~source,fill=0,value.var = "N")[,paste0(.SD,collapse = "|"),by=string]
   string    V1
1:      A 1|1|1
2:      B 1|1|0
3:      C 1|0|0
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that ? Not as neat as the one liner from the comments..
(with dplyr and data.table which you already use)

```
dt2 <- dt %>% 
   data.table::dcast(string ~ source) %>% 
   mutate(a_b_c = paste(a, b, c, sep="|")) %>%
   select(string, a_b_c)
```

giving

```
string a_b_c
1      A 1|1|1
2      B 1|1|0
3      C 1|0|0
```

Comment: I believe `dcast` is from `reshape2`, not `tidyr`

Comment: yes you are right I forgot to remove it... I thought it was in there at first.. it's actually from data.table and reshape2 (Edited answer accordingly) thks. The data.table dcast is faster for big data... _"dcast.data.table is a much faster version of reshape2::dcast, but for data.tables. More importantly, it's capable of handling very large data quite efficiently in terms of memory usage in comparison to reshape2::dcast"_